# Render html using AngularJS from sql database

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, angularjs

I want to save link with string in sql database column.I create anchor tag like this in codebehind

```
    var sFlag = String.Format(@"<a href=""https://localhost:44300/Resolve?post={0}"">resolve</a>", resolve.PostId);

    message.Content = "Please confirm your post by providing feedback by clicking "+sFlag;
```

and it gets save correctly in sql db column

[image]

but when I render in html it displays as string not as html

[image]

I am using angular js for getting data from server.

```
           $http({
                url: '/Message/GetAllMessages',
                method: "GET",

            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.message = data;

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
```

and finally looping thorough ng-repeat

```
 <ul ng-repeat="m in message">
    <li>
 <p style="margin-top:20px;">{{m.Content}}</p>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: In what way are you rendering the string in html?

Comment: simply displaying as it is like using angular i did this    <p style="margin-top:20px;">{{m.Content}}</p>

Comment: Your problem is probably with your AngularJS code to retrieve and display the data--you should update your post with that code as well.

Comment: Its simply an http get request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a little misleading. Basically you're not rendering HTML in your view that is retrieved from the database. You need to inject `$sce` into your controller and encode it before it's sent back to the view.

```
$scope.ContentWithHtml = data;
$scope.Content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ContentWithHtml);
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j25m/2/)

### UPDATE

Since you're using `ng-repeat`, you can do the following. Add this to your controller (after injecting `$sce`):

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;
```

Then you can use the following code in your view:

```
<ul ng-repeat="m in message">
    <li>
        <p style="margin-top:20px;" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(m.Content)"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Problem is how to render html with angular js or javascript aur jquery any thing

Comment: Which is what my answer solves. You'll need to edit the variable names to fit your code, but that is how you do it. Inject `$sce` into your controller, and use the `trustAsHtml` method to make that property able to render the HTML rather than writing it out as a string.

Comment: So i have to loop through all Content basically its a collection ?

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how you can achieve this within an `ng-repeat`